# Is there a shorthand way of checking if parameter exists and greater than zero?

Tags: php, php-7

I'm trying to check if a parameter is provided and passes a criteria, but seems verbose. This is what I have:

```
if (isset($request['limit']) && is_numeric($request['limit']) && (int)$request['limit'] > 0) {
    $post_params['posts_per_page'] = (int)$request['limit'];
}
```

I think it is safe, but is there a more concise way to achieve this while still remaining safe?

Comment: Function "empty"?

Comment: `is_numeric($request['limit'])` is uselsess here

Comment: I suppose you could do `if(intval($request['limit'] ?? 0) > 0)` but it might respond differently to string inputs if they start with numbers. Not sure.

Comment: @ZainFarooq but is (int)$request['limit'] > 0 still valid if it's not a int or will it die?

Comment: It is already typecasting it to int. We dont need to check if its numeric or not

Comment: Yes it's valid and should contain a number or any numeric string

Comment: But if the value is "2abc", then (int)$request['limit'] will result to "2"

Comment: @TruMan1 but it will not pass the second test: is_numeric()

Comment: Right, I was referring to @ZainFarooq who thinks "is_numeric" is useless here.

Comment: You can change `is_numeric` to `ctype_digit`, and you can omit the `(int)` in the condition, as the value will be implicitly type cast anyway. Besides that, it hardly gets any shorter…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use preg_match and see if the first character is [1-9] then any digits.
This will not allow zero values or empty or strings.

You can add a ternary isset but shorter than that is out of my reach.

```
if(preg_match("/^[1-9]\d*$/", (isset($str) ? $str : 0))){
    // Something
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193396/discussion-on-answer-by-andreas-is-there-a-shorthand-way-of-checking-if-paramete).

Comment: OP explicitly does not want negative numbers…

Comment: I have not seen OP expressing that. But just remove the `-?` and it's all good then.

Comment: *"`&& (int)$request['limit'] > 0`"*…

Comment: @deceze I don't usually pay that much attention to OPs code, more what they explain they want. I recalled it as "not zero", but I see in title it says "greater than zero". My bad

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter_input` or `filter_var`

```
if (isset($request['limit']) {
    $var = filter_var($request['limit'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, ['min_range' => 0]);
    if ($var) {
       $post_params['posts_per_page'] = $var;
    }
}
```

But ideally you would be doing this when you generate your $request array.

```
$request = [
    'limit' => filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'limit', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, ['min_range' => 0])
];
if ($request['limit']) {
    $post_params['posts_per_page'] = $var;
}
```

Comment: @deceze Yeah the first part is not really any better. I like the second option much better.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure it you consider this a shorhand...

```
$correct = @(preg_match('/^[1-9]\d*$/', $request['limit']));
```

"@" will supress any warning in this sentence, but the only warning you can get there is that the variable is not defined, so it is controlled.

Comment: That by itself won't do much good, so it's a partial solution at best.

Comment: @deceze Won't do good? It is literally answering the question!

Comment: `if (!empty($foo))` will let `'abcdef'` pass…

Comment: @deceze And you downvoted my answer because of that? And you are a moderator? Isn't the answer helpful?

Comment: Yes, I downvoted this answer because it's not a solution, at the very least not a *complete* solution, to the question. What other criterion should I apply here?

Comment: What criterion? What about the criterion that you get when hovering the downvote icon "This answer is not useful"?

Comment: Also `empty(-2)` will return `false` but OP needs to check that value is gt 0.

Comment: Partial answers should not be downvoted just because they are partial according to many discussions on Meta.

Comment: @Andreas The initial answer was so partial as to be pointless, the current answer has expanded on the initial and is now plainly wrong…

Comment: I agree with that, but that is not what you wrote up there. I'm not arguing on removing the downvote, just wanted to clarify to anyone reading that partial answers can be upvoted as they too can be helpful. But if the case is that the answer is wrong then it's a different matter.

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
if (isset($request['limit']) and intval($request['limit']) > 0) {
    $post_params['posts_per_page'] = (int)$request['limit'];
}
```

Comment: I believe you could even omit the `intval`, as type juggling will take care of that already.

Comment: Passes `123rjt`. So this does not apply.

Comment: Don't say "please use" please. Instead, *explain* what your answer does and *why* it works to resolve the OPs issue. They can then attempt to understand for themselves whether this helps for their case.

Comment: How is "You can use" a better explanation of why this works than "Please use"? Again: **add explanation as to why this works** Tell me why I need both these logical conditions to be larger than zero etc. Remember that you are not only answering to the OP, but also people who read this post years later in order to find out how to check whether a parameter exists and is greater than zero. They'll want to *understand* why this works.